# Code produces 'AttributeError' instead of correctly raising ValueError

Tags: python, attributeerror, valueerror

Using a regex expression, I am creating a function where certain criteria must be met (ex/ no white spaces allowed) and produces a tuple that is separated by a special character.

ex/ inputting a string of 'hello!world!hola' should produce a tuple of ('hello', 'world', 'hola').

I would like to raise a ValueError if the string does not meet my criteria. However, if the string does not meet my criteria, my code calls a AttributeError instead. Why is the function not properly calling the exception?

I tried to call a ValueError, but the function does not seem to catch my exception.

```py
def produce_tupule (s):

    re_pair = re.compile(r'''^                        
                           ([a-zA-Z0-9._+-]+)
                           \!                            
                           ([a-zA-Z0-9._+-]+)
                           \!
                           ([a-zA-Z0-9._+-]+)
                           $              
                        ''',
                        re.VERBOSE)
    try:
        return (re_pair.match(s).groups())
    except ValueError as e:
        print(e)
```

I expect the output of produce_tupule('hello     !world!hola') to result in the ValueError message since a whitespace exists in the string.

However, the error message points to the 'return:(re_pair.match(s).groups())' line and prints out an `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groups'`.

What is causing the function to not catch the exception and produce the AttributeError instead?

Answer (score 1):

`re.match` returns None instead of raising a `ValueError` if the regular expression given fails to match your input. Your code then tries to access the `.groups` member of the `None` return value, which fails with an `AttributeError`.

If you want to raise a `ValueError` if the regular expression given fails to match, you have to do so explicitly by replacing your `return (re_pair.match(s).groups())` line with code with explicit error checking:

```
match = re_pair.match(s)
if match is None:
    raise ValueError
return match.groups()
```